# How to echo variables values in check box using pop up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new in PHP. I have a code having a button. When button is clicked a modal will show. On modal, there are multiple check-boxes. When one of the check-boxes is checked, a value of that check-box should print. But I want to print that values in check-boxes on the modal.

**[Please Check This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/)**

Here is my code

```
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
      maxWidth: 800,
      maxHeight: 600,
      fitToView: false,
      width: '70%',
      height: '70%',
      autoSize: false,
      closeClick: false,
      openEffect: 'none',
      closeEffect: 'none'
    });

    $('.button1').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.various').click();
    });

  })
  .on('change', '[name=test-link]', function() {
    $('#print-values').empty();
    $('#print-values').append("<span>You've checked:</span><br />");
    $('[name=test-link]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $('#print-values').append(v + "<br />");
      }
    });
  });




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<a class="various" href="#form1" style='display: none;'></a>
<input class='button1' type="button" value="Link More Opinion" />
<div id='print-values'></div>
<div style='display: none;'>
  <form id='form1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="1" />
    <span>1</span>
    <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="2" />
    <span>2</span>
    <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='test-link' value="3" />
    <span>3</span>
    <br />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you print the values here in this div `print-values`. So you can use here a `textbox` instead of div.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/1/) check if this what you want?

Comment: @FrayneKonok I already tried it But its not working

Comment: what do you mean echo on file. saving on file?

Comment: @sunny, try this: [fiddlelink](https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/2/)

Comment: @guradio it show me an error on ` $('#print-values')append("<input type=text value="+v+"><br />");`

Comment: @FrayneKonok Sir i need it in input type text on in checkbox

Comment: @sunny in demo or your own code?because i dont see any possible error in the code

Comment: @sunny check again https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/57jok0hs/

Comment: @guradio When i use demo code in file then it show me error

Comment: can you share the code use in your file

Comment: @guradio Its Working now but now i have a problem if i use String rather than int then it show me some part of string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112246/discussion-between-guradio-and-sunny).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112258/discussion-between-sunny-and-guradio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append input and use the value in value attribute of input

`$('#print-values').append("<input type=text value='"+v+"'><br />");`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/6me6sjex/8/)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6me6sjex/4/), Check this out and let me know.

Change `<div id='print-values'></div>` to `<input type="text" id='print-values'/>`

**jquery:**

Only the portion, details in the fiddle.

```
$('#print-values').val("");
$('#print-values').append("<span>You've checked:</span><br />");
$('[name=test-link]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
       v = $(this).val();
       $('#print-values').val($('#print-values').val() +" "+ v);
    }
});
```